# Unable to run java class from ant script, have to provide multiple jars in classpath as well

Tags: java, exception, ant

My ant script looks like below -

```
    <java classname="com.ns.common.event.UpdateSiteImageProperties" failonerror="true" >    

        <arg value="${package}/"/>          
        <arg value="${install-base}/Enterprise/db/NewDB/${site.abbreviation}/site-installer.properties"/>   
        <classpath>
          <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
              <fileset dir="../lib">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
              </fileset>
              <fileset dir="../../Java">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
              </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </java>

</target>
```

I want to call the java class- UpdateSiteImageProperties from the jars which I am already including in the classpath. Can anyone tell where I am doing wrong?

Below is the exception which I am getting -

```
D:\NS\test8\Production\Enterprise\META-INF\build.xml:155: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.safenet.replication.util.BulletinBoardWriter.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.safenet.replication.util.BulletinBoardWriter.debug(Unknown Source)
        at com.ns.common.event.UpdateSiteImageProperties.main(UpdateSiteImageProperties.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:152)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: Which is line 155 in your `build.xml`?

Comment: What happens within `UpdateSiteImageProperties`?

Comment: line no. 155 is - <java classname="com.ns.common.event.UpdateSiteImageProperties" failonerror="true" >

Comment: My java file UpdateSiteImageProperties looks like -public class UpdateSiteImageProperties {  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  long installSize = 0;  
  UpdateSiteImageProperties objUpdateSiteImageProperties = new UpdateSiteImageProperties();  
  installSize = objUpdateSiteImageProperties.updateSiteProp(args[1]);   
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.load(new FileInputStream(args[2]));   
   String sizeStr = String.valueOf(installSize);   
   prop.setProperty("installer.size", sizeStr);   
   prop.store(new FileOutputStream(args[2]), "modified by NS installer");

Comment: Sorry because java file is not much in readable form. But basically it is updating a property file when I am passing some arguments from ant script.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my above question. If anybody else is facing the same issue then what they can do is create your own path reference and then point it to the classpath where you are calling your java class. These 10 lines of ant script ate my 3 days. But I am happy to share it so that at least someone can save their time. It should look like below -

```
<path id="dyna.jars">
                <fileset dir="./lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>          
        </path>         
        <java classname="com.ns.common.event.UpdateSiteImageProperties" failonerror="true" >    
            <classpath refid="dyna.jars" /> 
            <arg value="${package}/"/>          
            <arg value="${install-base}/Enterprise/db/NewDB/${site.abbreviation}/site-installer.properties"/>                   
        </java>
```